# Resolving Duplicate Class Conflict in MobileNetwork-runtime and Secure-agent-runtime Modules

Tags: java, android, kotlin, go

Description:
I'm encountering a duplicate class issue during the build process of my project. The error messages indicate that there are duplicated class definitions in the MobileNetwork-runtime and Secure-agent-runtime modules. Specifically, I'm seeing errors related to classes like go.Seq, go.Seq$GoObject, go.Seq$GoRef, and more, all duplicated between these two modules.

Problem:

Duplicate class go.Seq found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.Seq$GoObject found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.Seq$GoRef found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.Seq$GoRefQueue found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.Seq$GoRefQueue$1 found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.Seq$Proxy found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.Seq$Ref found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.Seq$RefMap found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.Seq$RefTracker found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.Universe found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.Universe$proxyerror found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)
Duplicate class go.error found in modules MobileNetwork-runtime (MobileNetwork.aar) and Secure-agent-runtime (Secure-agent.aar)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXn0H.png)

Steps I've Taken:

I've checked my dependencies to ensure that both MobileNetwork-runtime and Secure-agent-runtime are not being included redundantly.
I've verified that I'm using compatible versions of these modules.
I tried excluding one of the conflicting dependencies, but it didn't resolve the issue.
I attempted to clean my build and recompile the project, but the problem persists.
Request for Assistance:
I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve this issue and eliminate the duplicated class definitions. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or knows how to properly manage conflicting classes in different modules, your insights would be greatly appreciated. Are there any specific steps I should take, or configurations I should adjust in my build process to successfully resolve this conflict?

Thank you in advance for your assistance and expertise!